# JavaFX: How to portray a text file's contents into a TextArea

Tags: file, javafx, text

In JavaFX, I need to create a window that is entirely text, and I've tried a lot of things and none of them actually worked. I did manage to read every single line from a file correctly, and I hope it did append to the TextArea via TextArea.append, however, I don't know how to check if it did and how to portray it in a window. Here are the snippet of my class:

```
 private void printGUI(String type, double remainder[], double payment[], double credit[], double interest[], int term) {

    Scene scene;

    StackPane layout = new StackPane();
    scene = new Scene(layout, 600, 600);

    TextArea text = new TextArea();

    java.io.File file = new java.io.File("Ataskaita.txt");
    try {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            String line = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line); // this was only to check if it did read correctly
            text.append(line);        // don't know if this works
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Error!!");
    }

    //Below is the code that opens the winow with the title, however I don't know how to portray my TextArea into this window
    Stage window = new Stage();
    window.setScene(scene);
    window.setTitle(type + " grafikas");
    window.show();

}
```

Appreciate the help, will make necessary changes to the question accordingly to the comments!

Comment: You need to add the `TextArea` to the `StackPane`, which is the root of your `Scene`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never actually add the `TextArea` to the scene-graph. You create the `Scene` with `layout` as the root but you need to add the `TextArea` to `layout`'s children.

```
layout.getChildren().add(text);
```

You should also close the `Scanner` when finished with it. I suggest you use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to handle this automatically.

```
TextArea text = new TextArea();

File file = new File("Ataskaita.txt");
try (Scanner input = new Scanner(file)) {
    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        text.append(input.nextLine());
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

---

For more details about using JavaFX, see the [Getting Started with JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/index.html) tutorials.